# Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline: clean workspace / delete directory when build ends

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

we are using Jenkins multibranch (scripted) pipeline to run multiple builds, in parallel. Each one will create a new, uniquely named directory to checkout the code and run the test. Directories are uniquely named because they contain the branch name but also a random part like "JAA2A5HUZB7TRE4OTVXU7S...".

This means that after each build X directories (X = number of parallel jobs * number of branches) stay on the Jenkins node, filling disk space.

I wonder how I could automatically delete these directories.

A simplified version of my initial pipeline looks like this

```groovy
// Initialize the matrix
def matrix = [
  'foo',
  'bar',
]

// Initialize empty tasks map
def tasks = [:]

// Job status
successful = true

// Fill our tasks map from the Matrix data
for (x in matrix) {

  def job_name = x

  tasks[job_name] = {
    node('libvirt') {
        // Checkout repository first
        stage("$job_name - Checkout") {
          checkout scm
        }

        // Then build the machine
        gitlabCommitStatus('build') {
            stage("$job_name - Build") {
                  sh "./bin/build.sh ${job_name}"
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


//// Pipeline ////

notifyBuild('STARTED')

// Run tasks in parallel
try {
  parallel tasks
} catch(e) {
  throw e
} finally {
  if (successful) {
    notifyBuild('SUCCESS')
  } else {
    notifyBuild('FAILED')
  }
}

// Methods
def notifyBuild(String buildStatus = 'STARTED') {
   // used to send formatted e-mails 
}
```

I first added `deleteDir()` like this

```groovy
} finally {
  if (successful) {
    notifyBuild('SUCCESS')
  } else {
    notifyBuild('FAILED')
  }
  node('libvirt') {
    deleteDir()
  }
}
```

it raises an error and makes the build fail.

I then added a `cleanWs()` like this

```groovy
} finally {
  if (successful) {
    notifyBuild('SUCCESS')
  } else {
    notifyBuild('FAILED')
  }
  node('libvirt') {
    cleanWs()
  }
}
```

The output is

```
Running on node in /srv/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-deletedir-DRD7EKBEMMWJQZW6KKMQVVBTJTPTKLRAE2ITDK7V7IB5PTFXZUZA
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] step
[WS-CLEANUP] Deleting project workspace...[WS-CLEANUP] done
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

but the directory /srv/jenkins/workspace/pipeline-deletedir-DRD7EKBEMMWJQZW6KKMQVVBTJTPTKLRAE2ITDK7V7IB5PTFXZUZA still exists.

I'm looking for any solution to adapt this scripted pipeline (and for declarative pipeline if you know how) to be able to delete all directories created by the build.

Comment: A partial solution is to leverage the "Orphaned Item Strategy" with aggressive values. This doesn't answer the OP as it only applies to branches that are deleted (and PR branches for closed PR's). But it should help limit the disk space usage to some extent.

Comment: Will "Orphaned Item Strategy" remove the old workspaces for defunct branches across a cluster of remote agents? (including agents off-line when the branch deletion is noticed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution has been to add a try/catch/finally in the stage("$job_name - Build") step, something like

```
gitlabCommitStatus('build') {
    stage("$job_name - Build") {
        try {
            sh "./bin/build.sh ${job_name}"
         } catch (Exception e) {
            raise e
         } finally {
            deleteDir()
         }
    }
}
```

This doesn't delete all directories involved (because of this Jenkins issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41805) but it remove all the voluminous directories (containing code/build/artifacts...).

You needs to add "raise e" or build will always return Success, even if one of them fails.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you **can not delete the directory in which the build is still running**. The `deleteDir()` step just deletes the content of your workspace.

You could **trigger a job that runs after your build is finished** which deletes those directories. For this, you could use a pattern like `pipeline-deletedir-*`.

Comment: But downstream job needs: 1. to run on the exact same node that the job, 2. the exact directory name on this node

Comment: Moreover, if I understand this correctly https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41805 it seems that deleteDir() should work.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question (I personally use deleteDir() and for me it works) but as an alternative to save disk place you could consider discarding "old" builds in your multibranch pipeline:

```
stage ('Remove old builds') {
    //keep 10 builds per branch
    properties([[$class: 'BuildDiscarderProperty', strategy: [$class: 'LogRotator', artifactDaysToKeepStr: '', artifactNumToKeepStr: '', daysToKeepStr: '', numToKeepStr: '10']]]); 
}
```

Comment: I know that BuildDiscard removes all logs, artifacts and listing on the UI, but I'm quite sure it doesn't remove old directories, because we have this property set to 5 days, and directories (which are on nodes, not on the master) still exists.

Comment: Well sorry that wasn't much help, I do know that the build discarder is removing the job directories on the master.  Also as an aside, I actually do my deleteDir() in some instances at the beginning of the pipeline. I wish I could point to docs (hard to find stuff sometimes with Jenkins), but I looked at one of my builds that does this and Jenkins always seems to use the same workspace per branch (unless there is a parallel build - so I don't get a proliferation of workspace directories), but that's just me noticing behavior in my env and your mileage may vary.

Comment: In fact, in simple pipeline it uses the same directory, so deleteDir() at the beginning of the job is OK. We first started with that, so the problem didn't appear. When moving to multibranch pipeline, this random named directory feature appeared and this deleteDir() tip do not work anymore. In fact complete doc is hard to find for pipeline, and all features aren't implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is adding post section after all stages:

```
    stages {
         stage("$job_name - Build") {
             sh "./bin/build.sh ${job_name}"
         }
    }
        
    post {
         always {
             echo 'One way or another, I have finished'
             deleteDir() /* clean up our workspace */
         }
    }
```

Comment: A `post` directive only runs on one machine. If you have 2 or more stages in parallel running on different machines, then 1 or more of the machines will not have the `post` stage execute on them.